# replace values of some columns with a formula

Tags: r, dplyr

good afternoon and thanks for reading me. I'm trying to replace the values ​​of some columns with the division of that same column by another column (to avoid creating new columns with mutate), but I can't get it to work, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  this is my code:

```
x <- 
tibble(
  x1 = rep(2,10),
  x2 = rep(5,10),
  x3 = rep(5,10),
  x4 = rep(5,10),
  x5 = rep(5,10)
)
x[,2:5]/x[,1]
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  mutate(across(-x1, ~ .x/x$x1))

#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>       x1    x2    x3    x4    x5
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  2     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  3     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  4     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  5     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  6     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  7     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  8     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  9     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#> 10     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
```

---

Or in `base R`:

```r
x[2:5] <- x[2:5] / x[rep(1,4)]
x

#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>       x1    x2    x3    x4    x5
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  2     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  3     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  4     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  5     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  6     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  7     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  8     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#>  9     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
#> 10     2   2.5   2.5   2.5   2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `data.table` solution.

```
library(data.table)
cols=c('x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5')
setDT(x)[, c(cols):=lapply(.SD, \(y) y/x1), .SDcols=cols]
x
##    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
## 1:  2 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
## 2:  2 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
## 3:  2 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
## 4:  2 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
## ...
```

`data.table` columns are updated by reference when using the `:=` assignment operator, so the columns `x2` to `x5` are updated in place, without rewriting the `data.table`. This seems more in the spirit of your question, although you will not notice much of a difference unless you have millions of rows.